# Apple Pages.app ruining font display, any ideas?

Tags: pages, font

This truly makes no sense to me. As a graphic designer I've dealt with all sorts of RIP problems in the 90s and had issues with bad fonts in ttf, postscript, and opentype, and any number of other problems over the years, but never just one font display in only one app. *The font <strike>works perfectly in Preview.app, Stickies.app, Numbers.app, and Textedit.app (other Apple native/developed apps) and</strike>* fails miserably in <strike>Pages.app</strike> **[EDIT:] ALL Apple apps.** The system and app is up to date, and this problem has persisted since at least last summer's version of Pages while I was still using 10.13 and 10.14.

This particular issue is with ***Mrs Eaves Postscript Type 1*** font (whole family). For whatever reason, the font display is way off and I don't know of a way to help it out. Screen cap below is from three boxes of text, copied from each other and then using different character spacing. It's clear in the 6% and 20% that the spaces do render when larger values are used, however they all but disappear when not making the characters an uncomfortable space from each other. Thoughts?

[image: 0% -- 6% -- 20% char spacing]

Comment: Download photoshop trial version and test that out if it doesn't work there then something very weird is going on.

Comment: Thanks @William but I already have the full creative suite and have been using this font for more than a decade with zero issues there, and elsewhere including in MS apps (though only when I'd output as a pdf and not rely on the other users to own the font—as it's not an inexpensive font). It works fine in everything but the apple apps noted above, including the newest pro-level Affinity apps: Designer, Photo, and Publisher.